# Cannot access computer sometimes via tightvnc

Tags: remote-desktop

I have a lan of about 10-15 clients (depends on counting tablets and so on..). To access them from one station I use tightvnc which works like a charm - up to now. Sometimes I cannot access and I don't know why. When I access manually and so on, then it works, out of the blue.
Are there some commonly known "features" I don't know?

Comment: I don't understand how this is *too broad*.  I immediately recognized what his problem *might* be based on his title.

Answer (score 1):

**VNC** works on ports 5900 and up; 5900 for the service I believe then 5900+**n** for each **n** user desktops.

so if you are the 7th user for example and you get **desktop :7**, you would need port 590**7** in addition to 5900 being opened in your **firewall**.

depending on your linux distribution, they sometimes manage only a few ports upward or 5900,  your 10-15 clients is likely exceeding that and your firewall may be blocking VNC for those desktops.

a not uncommon *but not necessarily correct* practice is to just open ports 5900:5999 in your firewall, which would account for up to 99 users... *or disable firewall if that is acceptable on your LAN*

Comment: Interesting, thanks a lot! I will apply this. To add something I should have done before: When I restart the computer, then it works from the beginning on. Hence, my feeling is that it appears when the computer is idle and not used for a while (say >15min). Could this be possible somehow?

Comment: rebooting will clear the VNC connections list, starting in the basement at 5900 again and would work, as more and more user's connect going to ports 5900+n is when the firewall would start blocking.

Comment: I use SUSE, and by default they open ports 5900:5904 where 5901 is a non-persistent VNC remote desktop with resolution of 800x600; 5902 is :2 at 1024x768 res; and 5903 is :3 at 1600x1200 res.  Therefore as users do *vncserver* to get a persistent remote connection for themself things are fine for the first three users, user #4 and higher would get blocked by firewall and vnc would not work for them with no error message given.

Comment: as such anyone getting desktop :1, :2, or :3 is fine.  When it goes to :4 and above at port 5904 and above would be blocked by firewall, unless the firewall is customized.  *this is something that may be different for every linux distribution: rhel, sles, debian and so on.*

Comment: Thanks a lot again! This information is very helpful to understand the ongoing processes. I just noticed that this SE site is dedicated for unix/linux but I'm using tightvnc on windows because I have to due to business requirements. Personally I prefer linux too :)